# Load PNG resource to TGPImage

Tags: delphi, png, gdi+, embedded-resource

I would like to load PNG resource to TGPImage.

All the examples I found, use Bitmap Draw, which loses transparency.

Following example results just in black picture:

```
_shipImage := TGPImage.Create();
ms := TMemoryStream.Create();
png := TPngImage.Create;
try
  png.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'SHIP_RIGHT');
  ms.Position := 0;
  png.SaveToStream(ms);
  ms.Position := 0;
  sa := TStreamAdapter.Create(ms);
  _shipImage.FromStream(sa);
finally
  //sa.Free(); //Invalid pointer operation
  png.Free();
  ms.Free();
end;
```

Following also does not work:

```
_shipImage := TGPImage.Create();
rs := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'SHIP_RIGHT', RT_RCDATA);
rs.Position := 0;
sa := TStreamAdapter.Create(rs, soOwned);
_shipImage.FromStream(sa);
```

Comment: Try to use color management info of the image then, that is calling `_shipImage.FromStream(sa, True);`.

Comment: Some clues (but creates TBitmap) : `http://melander.dk/articles/alphasplash2/2/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the implementation of `TGPImage.FromStream` in `Winapi.GDIPOBJ` unit.

```
function TGPImage.FromStream(stream: IStream;
             useEmbeddedColorManagement: BOOL = FALSE): TGPImage;
begin
  result := TGPImage.Create(
      stream,
      useEmbeddedColorManagement
  );
end;
```

Although this method is an instance method, it does nothing with `TGPImage` instance and calls just `Create` !!!